# Image similarity detection with TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

Recently I started to play with tensorflow, while trying to learn the popular algorithms i am in a situation where i need to find similarity between images.

Image A is supplied to the system by me, and userx supplies an image B and the system should retrieve image A to the userx if image B is similar(color and class).

Now i have got few questions:

1. Do we consider this scenario to be supervised learning? I am asking
   because i don't see it as a classification problem(confused!!)
2. What algorithms i should use to train etc..
3. Re-training should be done quite often, how should i tackle this
   problem so i don't train everytime from scratch( fine-tuning??)

Comment: I could not understand the Image A. What is the role of Image A?

Comment: Image A is supplied to the system by me, and userx supplies an image B and the system should retrieve image A to the userx if image B is similar to A(color and class).

Comment: For others who end up here, I wrote a user-friendly blog post on using TensorFlow for measuring image similarity: http://douglasduhaime.com/posts/identifying-similar-images-with-tensorflow.html

Answer (score 9):

> Do we consider this scenario to be supervised learning?

It is supervised learning when you have labels to optimize your model. So for most neural networks, it is supervised.

However, you might also look at the complete task. I guess you don't have any ground truth for image pairs and the "desired" similarity value your model should output?

One way to solve this problem which sounds inherently unsupervised is to take a CNN (convolutional neural network) trained (in a supervised way) on the 1000 classes of image net. To get the similarity of two images, you could then simply take the euclidean distance of the output probability distribution. This will not lead to excellent results, but is probably a good starter.

> 2. What algorithms i should use to train etc..

First, you should define what "similar" means for you. Are two images similar when they contain the same object (classes)? Are they similar if the general color of the image is the same?

For example, how similar are the following 3 pairs of images?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Have a look at [FaceNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832) and search for "Content based image retrieval" (CBIR):

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval)
- [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=en&q=content+based+image+retrival&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically when i say "similar" i am talking about the class of the image and the color of it. for instance in your example the last ball should be "similar" to the second image in my case!

Comment: @iNDicator In this case, a classification approach (pre-training on ImageNet and comparing the probability distributions) should give acceptable results.

Comment: As suggested above, inception v3 seems to be a good start. I also noticed that few people applied nearest neighbor search but i am concerned with its performance/slowness.

Comment: Nearest Neighbor directly applied to the image is not going to work due to the [curse of dimensionality](https://martin-thoma.com/average-distance-of-points/) (have a look at the table and remember that this is in R^(150x150) or something similar)

Comment: If i recall correctly, there was someone who extracted features of his images from the inception model (pool3) and then he was applying Nearest Neighbor brute-forcing.. Basically i have to try different methods to find an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. This can be a supervised learning. You can classify the images into categories, if two images are in the same categories (or close in a category), you can think of them as similar.
2. You can use the deep conventional neural networks for imagenet such as [inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception). The inception model outputs a probability map for 1000 classes (which is a vector whose values sum to 1). You can calculate the distance of vectors of two images to get their similarity.
3. On the same page of the inception model, you will also find the instructions to retrain a model: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception#how-to-fine-tune-a-pre-trained-model-on-a-new-task

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look at the inception model and see how i can use it for my purpose